# R dplyr filter based on specific sequence based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to extract any rows such that `not` (`as per column x`) is followed by a `verb` (`as per column y`).

```
have <- tibble(x=c('notes','is','not','working','password','not','working'),y = c('NOUN','AUX','PART','VERB','NOUN','ADV','VERB'))

have
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  x        y    
  <chr>    <chr>
1 notes    NOUN 
2 is       AUX  
3 not      PART 
4 working  VERB 
5 password NOUN 
6 not      ADV  
7 working  VERB 

want
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x       y    
  <chr>   <chr>
1 not     PART 
2 working VERB 
3 not     ADV  
4 working VERB
```

My attempt is as below, tag each column for the presence of `not` and `VERB`, and then filter based on these tags.

Though this seems to be not so efficient because it requires 3-passes.

```
have %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(tag_not = ifelse(x == 'not',1,0),tag_verb = ifelse(y == 'VERB',1,0)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(tag_not == 1 | tag_verb == 1)
```

Comment: An alterative is to find the row indices where 'not' is followed by 'verb', `rep`eat them and add `0:1` to get both the focal row and the row after: `have[rep(which(head(have$x, -1) == "not" & tail(have$y, -1) == "VERB"), each = 2) + 0:1,]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of `lag` and `lead` -

```
library(dplyr)

have %>% 
  filter(lag(x) == 'not' & y == 'VERB' | x  == 'not' & lead(y) == 'VERB')

#   x       y    
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 not     PART 
#2 working VERB 
#3 not     ADV  
#4 working VERB
```

Or the same logic in `data.table` for large data -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(have)[shift(x) == 'not' & y == 'VERB' | 
            x  == 'not' & shift(y, type = 'lead') == 'VERB']
```

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that `lag(x) == 'not' & y == 'VERB'` to be sufficient without the other part of the OR `|`.

Comment: Yeah..it's not very intuitive but without the `|` part it only selects `y == 'VERB'` rows.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `semi_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

have %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = everything(),
        names_to ="names"
    ) %>% 
    filter(value=="not" | value=="working") %>% 
    semi_join(have, ., by=c("x"="value"))
```

Output:

```
  x       y    
  <chr>   <chr>
1 not     PART 
2 working VERB 
3 not     ADV  
4 working VERB
```